# C# ASP.NET MVC3 outperforms Ruby on Rails 3, Django?

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc, django

I was considering a fast-performing and scalable platform for high performance web application that also uses a database intensively. And it seemed to me that the natural approach is to pick some MVC framework like Rails, .NET MVC or Django. I've already had experience with both Rails and .NET but not with Python. And as far as my personal testing have shown C# with .NET MVC3 in most cases outperforms the Ruby on Rails 3 (for Rails I've used the unicorn and nginx for the http stuff). Anyone have some observations on that, or was my tests incorrectly held? Any examples with numbers and explanations would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You mind elaborating what your *personal testing* consisted of more precisely? For example showing the test code you have used for both platforms and the results you obtained?

Comment: As for initial conditions I was using the database with some generated table data like 100K-1M records and some not-too-complicated code to output values from there as a webpage (using ERB for Rails). Then, as a benchmark I was using Apache Benchmark (ab) and Siege to generate the pages per second and latency data correspondingly. Unfortunately could not test both in 100% equal conditions due limited availability of suitable environment, so no numbers or code here. Therefore the question if anyone tried something similar with more "scientific" approach?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least in terms of Rails vs Django it clearly looks like the latter IS faster, according to [these benchmarks](http://blog.curiasolutions.com/2010/11/the-great-web-technology-shootout-%E2%80%93-round-4-pyramid-vs-django-vs-tg-vs-rails-2-3/)

With ASP.NET MVC it looks more like there is some kind of conspiracy so no one actually tries to benchmark it :)

Answer (score 12):

The performance shouldn't be a dealbreaker when choosing a webframework, at least not when you are choosing from those 3, which are really proven in the battlefield.

If you just consider the language speed, C# - which is statically typed and JIT compiled, will always be the fastest. Python will come next (especially if you'll run Django on PyPy - which also does have a JIT, however not that mature) and Ruby will be the slowest (it always was, although it's improving).

Beside the language the database itself plays a big role, so lot depends on an ORM that given framework uses. Again, Entity Framework (which you're probably using with ASP.NET MVC) will be hardest to use inefficiently since lazy loading isn't a common practice there and the database model is created by hand usually. In Django, on the other hand, you write the model in Python, which sometimes may be too general out of the box.

Don't forget that when DB plays a crucial role, proper caching will always be the key factor regarding the performance. In contrast to ASP.NET MVC, Django and RoR are full stack frameworks and will give you more options out of the box, since they know all they need about models.

EDIT: If you want pure language speed comparison, have a look at http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=csharp&lang2=yarv
Read all the disclaimers (it's a benchmark of specific algorithm implementations that were ran on specific interpreter/compiler implemenentations so that's just a benchmark of those implementations) but keep in mind, that the C# implementation tested there is open source Mono version which for sure is slower than original MS Stack. So the differences you can see (c# implementation being 79 times faster than Ruby) may be even bigger.

Comment: Thanks! That kind of confirms my personal impression on topic. C# indeed seem to be the fastest of them all. However, have you considered compilable Ruby code? Plus, still no exact numbers ...

Comment: Exact numbers added (through Lanugage Benchmark link). What do you mean by compilable Ruby code?

Comment: I liked the new EDIT update. Nice link. Kind of confirms my impression mathematically. http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/performance.php?test=nbody - n-body test - 28 minutes for Ruby 1.9 and 35 seconds for C#. Thats huge! Even PHP was faster with rediculous 15 minutes. Seems C# performance is lightning fast only to be beaten by pure C/C++ implementation, but even there difference is mere 30%. Strange that Python went so badly with 20 minutes. I thought they've used some optimizations. Would you say again, after such results, performance shouldn't be a dealbreaker?

Comment: @SSpeedy - for typical Web applications, I would say it again, since:
1) Web apps are IO bound - network latency will be always order of magnitude bigger than CPU time
2) usually you can cache a lot
That's not the case for the long running background processes which usually in RoR projects are implemented in Java/Scala etc.
So don't forget about the performance but keep in mind other factors like huge productivity of full stack frameworks of Rails and Django as opposed to ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Network latency, traffic, browser caching this questions are off-topic. What I am concerned about is productivity of the framework itself.

Comment: Agree, performance not the only factor to look into when selecting the framework - http://podlipensky.com/post/2012/06/11/Choosing-web-framework-ASPNET-MVC-vs-Django-Python-vs-Ruby-on-Rails.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Django has a lot of smart caching mechanisms. Also, it encourages DRY, often resulting in cleaner code with less clutter that costs performance. It's also very easy to configure what kinds of middleware you want to hook into every request process.

So my argument wouldn't be that Django is necessarily faster than ASP.NET, but simply that people write better projects that in the end turn out faster.

Comment: Thanks. I think they all support some caching more or less, after all you can even cache the whole page using some reverse proxy like Varnish, but the question is more like about capabilities of those frameworks. How those do compare. If no caching used, all content is generated dynamically.

Comment: As you state, there are always clever solutions for performance (such as Varnish). I use Django, but I never much cared about performance, because there are endless tweaks. That said, I do use configure my system as good as I can, but I regard the design of my code as the holy grail, and this is where I've found Django to be far better than .NET, PHP etc. You can see a benchmark comparison here, it ranks Django highest: http://www.alrond.com/en/2007/jan/25/performance-test-of-6-leading-frameworks/